# How can I implement sticker function in my android application like Messenger or Line?

Tags: android

I am creating an android application which can send stickers like many other one. However, I don't know how to display stickers for users to select. I wonder if it is a kind of custom keyboard.

Comment: It isn't clear how much research you have done. This forum will help you debug code examples and explain oddities, but people prefer to see more specific details of what you are struggling with. Please elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) library to do that

Comment: I found some library to implement it before but I actually want to know how to create on my own. Is it a kind of custom keyboard?